# Simple Points Counter, Javascript is not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am trying to build a very simple points counter on a website. The numbers and button press aren't showing up in the main HTML. I am somewhat familiar with javascript, but not how to implement it onto a website. Help?

I've tried putting the javascript in a  tag in the header, but it still doesn't show up.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/public_html/script.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

  <div id="main-container">
    <div class="health-box" id="opponent-health">
      <img src="https://www.trzcacak.rs/myfile/full/208-2086167_runic-letter-othalan-rune-odal.png">
      <div class="health-counter" id="opponent-health-counter">
      </div>
      <div class="health-adjust health-minus" id="opponent-health-minus">
        &#9660;
      </div>
      <div class="health-adjust health-plus" id="opponent-health-plus">
        &#9650;
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="health-box" id="your-health">
      <p> LP </p>
      <div class="health-counter" id="your-health-counter">
      </div>
      <div class="health-adjust health-minus" id="your-health-minus">
        &#9660;
      </div>
      <div class="health-adjust health-plus" id="your-health-plus">
        &#9650;
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body> 
</html>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Variable set-up
  var opponentHealth = 0;
  var yourHealth = 10;

  $("#opponent-health-counter").html(opponentHealth);
  $("#your-health-counter").html(yourHealth);

  //Health adjust code
  $(".health-adjust").click(function() {
    if (this.id == "opponent-health-minus" && opponentHealth > 0) {
      opponentHealth -= 1;
    }
    else{
      opponentHealth -= 0;
    };
    if (this.id == "your-health-minus") {
      yourHealth -= 1;
    };
    if (this.id == "opponent-health-plus" && opponentHealth < yourHealth) {
      opponentHealth += 1;
    }
    else{
      opponentHealth += 0;
    };
    if (this.id == "your-health-plus") {
      yourHealth += 1; 
    };
    $("#opponent-health-counter").html(opponentHealth);
    $("#your-health-counter").html(yourHealth);
  });
});
```

Here is a link to a Pen where the programming works as expected. https://codepen.io/iph33r/full/LYPpOJm

Comment: You need another script tag to load jQuery, it must be before the one that loads your script.

Comment: @ths I think his problem is that he's missing the `<script>` tag that loads jQuery. You fixed this in your edit, so it's not the same question any more.

Comment: @Barmar if you see my edit changes the OP's intent in a way or another feel free to roll it back.

Comment: I was not aware I needed to call jQuery. I copied the code over and it still isn't showing up. Does it need to be in the head tag or in the body tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your script uses Jquery, you need to load that first.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/public_html/script.js"></script>
</head>
```